# How to remove characters which repeat more than twice in a string?

Tags: python, nltk

For example, I want to remove the duplicate characters like 
`hhhaaappy` to `hhaappy` since `h` and `a` repeat twice. 
I want to remove all the characters which repeat more than twice.
How to realize it in a fast way in python ?

Besides, is there any python module that can correct the word ?
like correct `hhhaaappy` to `happy` ?

Comment: Three or more in a row becomes 1?

Comment: Be careful what you ask for, the second part of your question implies that what you're looking for is a spell checker, which is likely best implemented in an easier way than you are attempting.

Comment: You need to edit your question. The first line is misleading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd thought it'll be cool to share this. Module called [autocorrect](https://github.com/phatpiglet/autocorrect).

It works by using a [Candidate Model](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html), by performing "simple edit" to the word. For example, it processes "**deletion->remove a letter**", "**transposition->swap two adjacent letters**", "**replacement->change one letter to another**", "**insertion->add a letter**".

Therefore, `hhhaaappy` might not work but `hhapy` or `hhapppy` could work.

```
>>> from autocorrect import spell
>>> spell('hhhaaappy')
'hhhaaappy'
>>> spell('hhapy')
'shapy'
>>> spell('happpy')
'happy'
>>> spell('hhapppy')
'happy'
```

Comment: But doesn't answer the question in any capacity.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, question asked for a module that would correct a word. The module I shared does that. Also, Ajax1234 did a great job answering the first part of the question. So I'm not going to work on that question.

Comment: Thanks. Before I use the function, how can I know whether there is a spell error in current word ?

Comment: >>> spell('happyyyyyyyyyyy')
'happyyyyyyyyyyy'
>>> spell('haaaaappyyyyyyyyyyy')
'haaaaappyyyyyyyyyyy'

Comment: After reading the [source code - Github](https://github.com/phatpiglet/autocorrect), the way it works is with a [Candidate Model](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html), by performing "simple edit" to the word. For example, it processes "deletion->remove a letter", "transposition->swap two adjacent letters", "replacement->change one letter to another", "insertion->add a letter". 

Therefore, as I've shown in my answer `hhhaaappy` might not work but `hhapy` or `hhapppy` could work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = "hhhaaappy"
new_s = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s)]
final_s = ''.join(''.join(b[:-1]) if len(b) > 2 else ''.join(b) for a, b in new_s)
```

Output:

```
'hhaappy'
```

Comment: I test  "hhhuuuckcuqqqqaaappy"  , the output is hhuuckcuqqqaappy which contain three 'q'

Comment: @yanachen what would you like the output to be for `"hhhuuuckcuqqqqaaappy"`?